# Why does WICD work and Network-Manager does not? And why no bluetooth?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, bluetooth, wicd

I had a previous question that never really got solved, but to sum it up, I've been unable to get network-manager to work with my surface pro 3 running ubuntu 17.10. I've tried the usual suspects: disable mac randomization, try WICD and use NDISwrapper. They all showed minor improvements, but after a few minutes to a few hours, my wifi would still drop. That is until yesterday when I had the idea to try all three at once. VOILA! with randomization disabled, WICD instead of network-manager AND NDISwrapper in place and I have a non-stop internet connection. The pitfall: Network-manager also controls my bluetooth apparently. no network-manager, no bluetooth. I went to enable bluetooth and even though i had "removed" network-manager, it came back, took control of the wifi and within minutes, i lost my internet connection. I guess my question is, why can WICD maintain a perfect connection when network-manager fails within minutes. and also, why can't i control my bluetooth independently? Is it too much to ask to have wifi AND bluetooth?

as per a request below:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless [11ab:2b38]
    Subsystem: SafeNet (wrong ID) 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless [0001:045e]
    Kernel driver in use: mwifiex_pcie
    Kernel modules: mwifiex_pcie
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:07bf Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:07be Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1286:204b Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07dc Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2571:4101

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)
[    0.084044] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.469181] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (98)
[   12.977100] usb 1-6: Product: Bluetooth and Wireless LAN Composite Device
[   12.997725] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.997743] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.997746] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.997748] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.997753] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.036773] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.036774] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.036777] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.473849] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.473854] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.473858] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got desperate and uninstalled all of the bluetooth packages I had installed in my software center. I don't know why there where multiple different packages, bluetooth manager being one of them. After uninstalling everything, i reinstalled bluetooth manager and it worked. I don't know why, but it did and everything is fine now. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

WICD is great for WiFi management.  If you chose to stay with WICD, you could use [`bluez`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bluez) to manage your bluetooth.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

You can learn about how to manage connections on the CLI, using `bluetoothctl` or try out `blueman` for an easier, GUI experience.

There is a community [Bluetooth Doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) for other ideas and more details.